# How to calculate this residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to calculate this residue $$Res\left(\frac{\ln z}{z(z+1)},0\right).$$ Is it $\infty$? And if this could not be calculated, then how to calculate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x+1}dx$$ by changing variables $y=e^x$.

Comment: I believe the $Lnz$ in the numerator shall be the logarithm of $z$? The logarithm doesn't have an isolated singularity in $0$, so the residue of $\dfrac{\log z}{z(z+1)}$ in $0$ is not defined.

Comment: Generally speaking, $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx=(1-2^{-n})\cdot\Gamma(n+1)\cdot\zeta(n+1)$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx=\Gamma(n+1)\cdot\zeta(n+1)$$ where $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ , and $\zeta(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^n}$ is a [rational multiple of $\pi^n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers) for even values of *n*.

Comment: @Lucian Then how can I computer this integral using the residue theorem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631138/how-to-compute-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracxex1dx-using-the-residue-t/631190#631190